# How does Haskell's putStrLn perform its effect?

Tags: haskell, io

I'm wondering how `putStrLn` works: I can see that it has type `IO ()` but I've no notion of how Haskell actually performs the side effect of writing to standard out.

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Test"
```

How does this program write to standard out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Using C

Seeing in [base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/System.IO.html#putStrLn) that

```
putStrLn s      =  hPutStrLn stdout s
```

I followed a trail of functions that eventually lead me to [`c_write`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/System.Posix.Internals.html#c_write) which is defined like this:

```
foreign import capi unsafe "HsBase.h _write"
  c_write :: CInt -> Ptr Word8 -> CUInt -> IO CInt
```

Thus, it seems that the effect of writing to stdout is performed by calling native code.

---

Some stops on my journey jumping from function to function (the arrow → means that the left function calls the right one):

[`hPutStr'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Handle.Text.html#hPutStr%27) → [`writeBlocks`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Handle.Text.html#writeBlocks) → [`commitBuffer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Handle.Text.html#commitBuffer) → [`writeCharBuffer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Handle.Internals.html#writeCharBuffer).

Then, `writeCharBuffer` calls the typeclass method [`BufferedIO.flushWriteBuffer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.BufferedIO.html#flushWriteBuffer) on `stdout`.

Continuing in [`stdout`'s typeclass instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Handle.FD.html#stdout) for `BufferedIO`:

`flushWriteBuffer` → [`writeBuf'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.FD.html#writeBuf%27) → [`writeBuf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.BufferedIO.html#writeBuf). `writeBuf` calls `IODevice.write` on a `RawIO` device, also a typeclass for which there is an [instance for stdout](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.FD.html#line-97). `write` relays to [`fdwrite`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.FD.html#fdWrite).

`fdWrite` calls [`writeRawBufferPtr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.FD.html#writeRawBufferPtr) → [`do_write`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.FD.html#local-6989586621679367082) which finally calls [`c_write`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/System.Posix.Internals.html#c_write).

Comment: `putStrLn` is the only thing defined by *Haskell*. Everything below that, in this case from `hPutStrLn` on down, is an implementation detail of GHC.